# Why SMS app won't save drafts?

Tags: 8.1, sms

How do I get stock SMS app to save my draft messages and appear in conversations for further editing at any time. Many times I write a SMS and do something else with other apps and return back my message then find nothing.

My  Lumia 640XL with Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMS app do save drafts. To access drafts, follow these steps :

1. Open Messaging app.
2. Tap on the three dots (**...**) located on the bottom right corner.
   [image: Drafts option in SMS app]
3. Click on drafts.
4. You will see all your saved messages here.
   [image: Drafts folder]

**Note** : Any unsent message that is typed will be automatically stored in drafts.

**Update** : Another method of accessing drafts

If a message is saved in a conversation, you can access the draft by simply clicking on the conversation. These drafts will be available under drafts folder too.

[image]

Comment: I thought the process was straight forward and seamless as on Android. Why do I have to dig deep to reach those drafts? On Android Any unsent message would be saved as a draft and appear automatically in SMS app without diving in any settings.

Comment: @mms911 _"On Android Any unsent message would be saved as a draft and appear automatically in SMS app"_ My answer clearly says that Windows phone **does automatically save any unsent message** in drafts. You are **not** diving into any settings. You are clicking the drafts folder in more option. I have updated my answer to add another method to access drafts. I don't understand why you are digging deep to access drafts? All the drafts can be accessed in  **2-3 clicks** (_Message app->Conversation_ or _Message app->More->Drafts_)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, If you are sending a text to a specific contact, that is, replying to a thread, the message you'd have typed, but not finished, nor sent, appears under the thread of that contact as a draft in the message input field